# Table name containing special characters '[' and ']'

Tags: sql-server, create-table

I want to create table in sql server with using [ ] in the name.it's mean [ ] symbol is a part of table name.how can i do it?i use sql server 2008 r2

Comment: Why on this earth you want name to include such "symbol".

Answer (score 3):

You can use `]` if you enclose the table name in double quotes:

```
create table "[Mu]Ha[Ha]" (id int);
```

Note that using [irregular identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) is an invitation for trouble down the road.  Not all client libraries will deal with them correctly, and your code will become harder to read for other developers.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a table(or column names) using `[` `]` in it, but it is considered a bad practice.

```
CREATE TABLE "tabl[eO]ne" (ID int NOT NULL)
```

the above will work, but is considered bad practice, because it makes the code harder to read and understand, not only for you but also for other developers working on the database after you.

in SQL people use brackets around a table/column name if the name contains spaces or certain special character, like the example below:

```
CREATE TABLE [Table One]
CREATE TABLE [Table-One]
CREATE TABLE [Table_One]
CREATE TABLE [Table*One]
...
```

This still isn't a good practice but it follows the "best practice" guidelines.

Best practice of all : 
**Avoid using special characters, numbers or spaces in a table/column name at all.**

Answer (score 0):

Enclose within square brackets.
But its Not a good practice
["name[a]abc"]

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome this by using double bracket. see below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[[tbl]]](id INT)
```